# badge or badge count not show using react-native-android-badge on vivo v7

Tags: android, react-native, notifications, onesignal

I am developing an app using react native. It need to do some push notification. I am using onesignal and react-native-android-badge to do it. I have tested on mi a2, Asus z010d and LG magna, everything run as expected. When I test on vivo v7 [vivo 1718 (android 7.1.2)], the notification is popped up but the badge or badge count not show. 
do I miss some permission?
does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`react-native-android-badge` is a wrapper for `ShortcutBadger`. Unfortunately not all Android devices support badges.

`ShortcutBadger` provides a [list](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger#supported-launchers) of supported devices, Vivo does not seem to be one of them.

<strike>`ShortcutBadger` also provides an app to test whether it works on your device. You can download that from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.leolin.isbadgeworking).</strike> Unfortunately the app is no longer available on the PlayStore and the link is broken

Comment: thank you. it seems each vendor has their own implementation how to set the badge. and newer android only show dot badge. so I tried different launchers to make the badge showed